# Does the EU need a condemnation from a member state court to add an organization in the EU's terrorist organization list?

Tags: european-union

On January 23, the High Representative of the EU for Foreign Affairs [Josep Borrell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josep_Borrell) [claimed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAjbP3nSEb0)  that the EU would need a "condemnation from a court in one member state" to insert the [Islamic Revolutionary Guard Corps (IRGC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_Revolutionary_Guard_Corps) in the EU's list of terrorist organizations.

Is this true?

According to the [European Council's web page on the EU terrorist list](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/policies/fight-against-terrorism/terrorist-list/#criteria):

> The common position establishes that the list will be drawn up from precise information indicating that a decision has been taken by a judicial or equivalent competent authority in respect of the person, group or entity concerned. This decision may concern:
>
> - initiation of investigations or prosecution for a terrorist act or an attempt to carry out or facilitate such an act
>   conviction for any of those actions
> - Persons, groups and entities identified by the UN Security Council as being related to terrorism and against whom it has ordered sanctions may also be added to the list.

Does "common position" mean that the procedure is written in law or that it's just common practice? Have all other entities on the EU's terrorist organization list been condemned by a member state court? And what is an "equivalent competent authority"?

Comment: This is an article by a German law researcher answering the question: https://verfassungsblog.de/why-declaring-the-iranian-revolutionary-guards-a-terrorist-group-is-a-trickier-business-than-one-may-think/

Answer (score 2):

> Does "common position" mean that the procedure is written in law or that it's just common practice?

Neither. It means that that is the position of all member states in common.

> Have all other entities on the EU's terrorist organization list been condemned by a member state court?

Not necessarily - the court does not have to be in a member state. A finding by a US, Australian, or Indian court for example may be sufficient.

> And what is an "equivalent competent authority"?

What it says. Examples might be a [military tribunal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_tribunals_in_the_United_States) or a [Royal Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_commission).